# Python: update entries field from mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

So I have `mongo db` that I starts dorm `docker` and put several entries:

```
(
id - int,
mod - boolean,
data - text,
)
```

So i want to search for N entries form my `data base` with `mod=false`:

```
results = self.dbcol.find({'mod': False}).limit(3)
```

So my results return 3 elements And for each entry at this result i want to change `mod` field to `true`.

So this is what i have try:

```
for entry in results:
    entry['mod'] = True
```

And this is not changed my field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [update_one](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one)

```
update = { "$set": { 'mod': True } }

for entry in results:
    self.dbcol.update_one({ _id: entry['_id'] }, update)
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over a cursor is not a performance-efficient way if the `N` is a big number.
An efficient way would be to take advantage of `find_one_and_update` method of `pymongo` and call it `N` times, thereby keeping the disk usage low if `N` is big.

```py
import pymongo
from pymongo.collection import ReturnDocument

for _ in range(0,N):
   returned_document = self.dbcol.find_one_and_update(filter={ 'mod': False }, update={"$set": { 'mod': True }}, return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER)
   # return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER --> returns modified document after updating it
   # return_document=ReturnDocument.BEFORE --> returns original document before updating it
```